# How to detect if code is python 3 compatible

Tags: python

I'm doing static code analysis using openstack/bandit. Do have a lot of repositories, some of those are in python 2 other in python 3. How can I detect if code is syntactically compatible with python 3 without running the code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's one thing you might want to do. I think it's the easiest way you can know if code is compatible at least syntaxically.

Have a python3 program load the python modules (without executing them). If the code is compatible, it will load the module, if it isn't... it will raise a syntax error.

Use the `ast` module.

```
import ast

def test_source_code_compatible(code_data):
    try:
        return ast.parse(code_data)
    except SyntaxError as exc:
        return False

ast_tree = test_source_code_compatible(open('file.py', 'rb').read())
if not ast_tree:
    print("File couldn't get loaded")
```

If the code can't be loaded it will raise a `SyntaxError` error.

Documentation of the [Ast Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

If the abstract syntax tree can't be loaded, then you may have to check for python2 methods that don't exists in python3 or methods that changed their behaviour.

For example the division in python3 and python2 works differently. In python2, the division divide in integers so the result of a division will be different if you don't use the same division scheme. In that case, you'll have to look if the module is importing `from __future__ import division` to have the same behaviour in python2 and python3.

Here's an exhaustive list of things that you might want to handle:

http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

Loading the ast of the module will give you right away things that absolutely can't work.. but knowing if code that can be parsed will work in python3 is subject to many false positive. It's hard even impossible to accurately detect if code will actually work 100% in python2 and 3 without actually running it and comparing the results.

Comment: If the code is compatible, it will load the module and execute all of the top-level code in that module.

Comment: @vaultah that's ridiculous. Didn't I write _without executing them_ ?

Comment: Maybe you should write how you'd load them.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix It's somewhat written *now*, not originally. And you still don't show how `code_data` came to be.

Comment: @StefanPochmann at the time you wrote your comment it was already written in the answer. But if you insist on how to get code_data...

Comment: While PEP-8 states that source files _should_ use UTF-8, Python supports other encodings. This can lead to valid programs to be wrongly reported as a SyntaxError if you open them as text without checking the encoding. The original code snippet incorrectly reported files with a byte order mark (BOM) as a syntax error. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations

Comment: Nothing was printed out for me.
    print("ast_tree = ", ast_tree) #ast_tree =  <_ast.Module object at 0x00000252ABEAD2E0>
    print("ast_tree type = ", type(ast_tree)) # ast_tree type =  <class '_ast.Module'>

Answer (score 21):

Basic validation would be if the 2to3 tool prints any diffs (s. https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html for basic usage)

on a simple file like a.py:

```
import urllib2

print "printing something"
```

you'd get:

`> 2to3 a.py`

```
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored a.py
--- a.py    (original)
+++ a.py    (refactored)
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-import urllib2
+import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

-print "printing something"
+print("printing something")

RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: a.py
```

Comment: ;-) Same idea, I just can't post answers for some reason. :D +1

Comment: I think that would give a lot of false answers when fed Python 3 code. For example I just tried it and it wants to replace `print(42)` with `print((42))`, ouch. So you'd see a diff and think it's Python 2?

Comment: @StefanPochmann just verified that, it seems to interpret it (wrongly) as a tuple. ```print ("testing")``` is not being modified

Comment: Could it be the case that 2to3 assumes that input code is always in python2?

Comment: That could very well be the case.  The link in this question is called `25.4. 2to3 - Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation` -  https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 10):

The most basic validation that you could do ensure your code is python3 compatible **syntaxically** is to run *pylint3* for that particular module and look for errors.

**Install pylint3**

```
sudo apt-get install pylint3
```

**Run pylint3 for a python module**

```
pylint3 -E <module.py>
```

The above could be used to catch syntax errors in a module with respect to python3.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE for this. Just open the python files in the pycharm editor, it will show warnings if the code is not compatible to Python2 or Python3.

Here is the screenshot where it shows print command syntax warning.
[image]

Comment: Minimum Individual cost is $89/year.

Comment: @SDsolar this future [supported in community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: Is this still erroneous in today's Python 3?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "compileall" module like so:

```
python3.6 -m compileall -q .
```

Modify appropriately for the python version you want to use.

Python3 (since 3.something) puts compiled modules into a `__pycache__` directory, with a arch-specific extension, so they won't conflict with Python2 or other Python3 versions.

The given command will just show errors, and will recurse from the current directory. Use `python3.6 -m compileall --help` to reveal ALL the OPTIONS.